# .htaccess redirecting all domains sharing same ip

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use this

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "localhost"
ErrorDocument 403 https://localhost/john/
```

Which works, but it takes all of my domains which are on the same server using the same IP address and redirecting them all to the primary domain's https version, how can I filter it to only redirect the one?

So far this is the only one that has worked eg. actually redirected using the virtual host port declaration with :443

Any help would be appreciated